# Use Post-build Actions as Build steps

Tags: hudson, jira, hudson-plugins

Is it possible to use Post-build Actions as Build steps? The problem I have is that the JIRA Hudson Integration Plugin doesn't allow me to use some steps as build steps, but just like Post-build actions. I use the following actions: "Mark a JIRA Version as Released", "Move issues matching JQL to specified version". When I use them as post actions and the job fails, this steps get executed at the end and this is really annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This plugin will do what you are asking for:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Any+Build+Step+Plugin